# ESLint: Running ESLint for one rule with a big rule object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am trying to run ESLint in my React project for only to check one specific (e.g: *max-len*) rule like this:

```
eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --rule "{'max-len': ['error', { code: 120, ignoreComments: true, ignoreTrailingComments: true, ignoreUrls: true, ignoreStrings: true, ignoreTemplateLiterals: true, }]}"
```

But results are also showing errors for other type of errors.

Here is my *.eslintrc.js* file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'react-app',
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'jsx-a11y',
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  // parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2017,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'max-len': ['error', {
      code: 120,
      ignoreComments: true,
      ignoreTrailingComments: true,
      ignoreUrls: true,
      ignoreStrings: true,
      ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
    }],
  },
};
```

I have also tried to run with ignoring file *.eslintrc.js* using `--no-eslintrc` like this:

```
eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --no-eslintrc --rule ....same-rule-above
```

This time I only get one max-len error and the rest are errors for parsing the import keyword:

```
/Users/olcayertas/10n/src/util/helpers.ts
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

/Users/olcayertas/10n/src/util/routes.ts
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved

/Users/olcayertas/10n/src/util/ui-helpers.ts
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

✖ 196 problems (196 errors, 0 warnings)
```

How can I run ESLint for just one rule with a rule object?

Comment: See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#-rule

Comment: What do you mean by "exp" (in the first sentence)?

Answer (score 1):

I find the problem and here is the answer. Because our project is using [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript), we need the configuration on the `eslintrc.js` file, so using `--no-eslintrc` doesn't work. Instead we had disabled the extended rules (not the plugins):

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  extends: [
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    //'plugin:react/recommended',
    //'arbnb',
  ],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'import/no-unresolved': ['error', { ignore: [ '.svg' ] } ],
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Since I want to see the errors for imports, I have left plugins and rules enabled for the imports. After disabling the extended rules I run this command:

```
eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx
```

And it works perfect! This way we can add rules step by step.

Comment: It's probably easier to create a "base" set of rules that you can use for linting from command line and your actual ESLint config file will simply extend the base and the other presets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your .eslintrc file to keep your configuration (parser, plugin settings, etc), you can use [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) with the `--rule=max-len` flag.  This will respect your normal configuration, but only show you errors from that rule, and give the option to fix them, if the rule is auto-fixable.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of eslint-nibble.